# How to prevent intentional down voting in stackoverflow -- you'd like it

Tags: discussion, profile-page, voting

Yesterday, I saw a post where I answered a newbie's post about where to look for the answer for his question.

Someone great! got good amount of time and didn't like that I gave links in my answers reply to his post.

I agreed with this great user and frankly said, I did it so that the newbie user can look into the links, learn by his own (as the links had very good information (I myself tried it) and actually I was just about to log off; but I think the great user didn't like my cheerful reply.

He got a chance and down voted all of my recent posts/answers in which there were good amount of posts which helped many users online and had popular question badge on it.

:) to my knowledge, he downvoted atleast close to 30-40 posts.

Hats off to the great user!! in doing a great job (today is Friday).

Wondering if there's a way to avoid someone doing it OR if they do, then automatically sending a Hi Fi message to the great user.

**See below**:
[image]

Comment: ^ Meta is that way ^

Comment: If one user downvotes several of your posts in a short period of time, it's automatically corrected by the system. I think you sometimes need to give it a day or so.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: @Michelle - thanks for sharing that. I'll check if my down votes comes back but I don't care much about my ranking here, it's just like people sometime get so cringey (I guess they didn't take their healthy breakfast that day).

Comment: Links are for comments, not answers.

Comment: ok, I checked. I found that the auto correct thing didn't do the correction correctly. my points didn't revive to the state before this person started down voting after having 4 bottles of vodka.

Comment: That is shockingly petty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ironically, here is a link with the answer to that question.

[How can I report a specific bad user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66444/how-can-i-report-a-specific-bad-user)

Seems that you can use the "contact" button on the site to report the user. I don't think you can flag a downvote specifically, but maybe they made some other offenses that you could report to get their attention.

Comment: :) Thanks. It's funny that someone up-voted my post to 1, then it came back to 0, and now it's back to -1. I agree. We are all here to help each other but don't know why someone would go and down vote a user's post (when the person's reputation is more than 35K and has reached/helped more than 1.7M people).

Comment: I dunno. I am pretty new here, needed some help for once so tried to contribute more hoping for some internet karma to help me out.

Comment: For serial-down voting there is really no reason to do anything, those get detected and reversed. There is always a slight chance that (admitted that this  case is extreme) someone else down voted the questions and then you accused the wrong person. If the down votes don't get reversed after 24-hours, flag one your own posts for moderator attention and explain clearly that you think serial down votes didn't get reversed. Use the contact the team as a last resort.